# compiling FMU with Jmodelica

Tags: jmodelica

I have a problem compiling FMU's in Jmodelica. for a medium size model I get the following error.

[image]

I already chanded the runtime parameter of JAVA in control panel and also tired setting the JVM allocated memory as high as possible using Xmx command. I'm running it on a pc with 128GB RAM. 
Does anyone know how can I solve this issue in Jmodelica?

Comment: It's better quote the error than post a picture of it.  That way it's searchable for others.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM that is being used from JModelica does not take into account the system settings for the JAVA runtime parameter. You'll need to set it in the compile_fmu command. I.e.

```
compile_fmu(...., jvm_args="-Xmx10g")
```